# Ping loop stopping if Host Not Found

Tags: c#

I have an application that pings many devices in parallel. Everything works fine if I am using IP addresses. However, if I have Host Names, and one Host Name is not found, all pings after just stop.

I have tried wrapping it in a try/catch and no errors are being caught.

**Note**: I have many lines of code, so I am going to only try to add parts that are needed. If I missed something please let me know and I will gladly update.

With the below code, if all the inputted `ipAddress` are IP addresses, everything will complete correctly. However, if there is a single bad, or not found Host Name, it will not complete (note: if they are all good Host Names, it will also complete fine).

```
try
            {
                Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopState) =>
                {
                    Ping ping = new Ping();
                    int timeout = 2000;
                    int highping = 300;

                    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString(), timeout);


                    this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
                    {
                        if (ipAddress[i] == primary4kIP.Text)
                        {
                            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= highping)
                            {
                                primary4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.high;
                            }
                            else if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime < highping)
                            {
                                primary4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.up;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                primary4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.down;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ipAddress[i] == backup4kIP.Text)
                        {
                            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= highping)
                            {
                                backup4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.high;
                            }
                            else if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime < highping)
                            {
                                backup4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.up;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                backup4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.down;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ipAddress[i] == backupdrab4kIP.Text)
                        {
                            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= highping)
                            {
                                backupdrab4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.high;
                            }
                            else if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime < highping)
                            {
                                backupdrab4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.up;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                backupdrab4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.down;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ipAddress[i] == esxi4kIP.Text)
                        {
                            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= highping)
                            {
                                esxi4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.high;
                            }
                            else if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingReply.RoundtripTime < highping)
                            {
                                esxi4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.up;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                esxi4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.down;
                            }
                        }

                    });

                });
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

Comment: You need to move the `try...catch` block into the loop block to not break it. `try..catch` each IP. Also note, when you call an image from `Properties.Resources`, you get a new instance from it, to avoid the memory leak problems, dispose of the `.Image` properties before assigning new ones. i.e. `primary4kStatus.Image?.Dispose(); primary4kStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.high;`. Or back them in class variables or a list and dispose of them when you close/dispose the container (Form...).

Comment: Woah, that was simple! Also, thanks for the advise on the images, doing that now!

Answer (score 3):

Add a try catch for each case so that it will catch only the missing one and the code will continue to the other case